# Overloading a macro implemented function in C++

Tags: c++, macros, operator-overloading

This is a section of my C++ source code.

```
int Serial::getc() {
return std::getchar();
}
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
In file included from Serial.cpp:2:0:
Serial.cpp:9:13: error: no ‘int Serial::_IO_getc()’ member function declared in 
class ‘Serial’
int Serial::getc() {
^
```

What should I do? It seems that I am trying to overload a function that was implemented using a macro, and my overloading function's name got replaced.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to write the command you use to compile.

Comment: If `getc` is a function-like macro, you can do `int (Serial::getc)()`

Answer (score 0):

You could `#undefine` the macro, but be aware that you then won't be able to use it in the subsequent sourcecode.

Overriding itself is not possible with Macros.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, getc is a macro in your ("standard") library. The better is to not use it as a name for your own function... The more better would be it not to be a macro (but this requires to modify the library).

(you can try "mygetc") ...